# Fetch records from database according to the dates

Tags: mysql, sql

**Problem**

I have developed a gaming system where users do certain amount of activity and to do that they need to have Gadget. They're allowed to change their gadget in the middle of the game. For instance a user was using **XBox** from the start(**29 Nov 2013**) of the game until **03 Feb 2014** and now he decided to switch his gadget to **Wii** then from my database I want to fetch data of that user for XBox and for Wii both according to the dates.

I am using the following query, there's a data in the database but still the query results Zero records. Any suggestions will be great!

**Query**

```
SELECT * 
FROM game_scores
WHERE username =  "joe@example.com"
AND gadget_data_type =  "Activity"
AND gadget_sub_data_type =  "running"
AND (
gadget_name =  "XBox"
AND STR_TO_DATE( date_time,  "%a, %e %b %Y %H:%i:%s" ) >= STR_TO_DATE(  "Fri, 29 Nov 2013 00:00:00",  "%a, %e %b %Y %H:%i:%s" )
)
AND (
gadget_name =  "Wii"
AND STR_TO_DATE( date_time,  "%a, %e %b %Y %H:%i:%s" ) >= STR_TO_DATE(  "Mon, 3 Feb 2014 00:04:46",  "%a, %e %b %Y %H:%i:%s" )
)
ORDER BY df_id DESC
```

Comment: what type is `date_time`? `timestamp`, `datetime`, `varchar`?

Comment: put some table data or make sql fiddle

Comment: @Barranka it's a varchar

Comment: what is date_time value?

Comment: **date_time** value is same as it is in the query i.e. **Fri, 29 Nov 2013 00:00:00**

Comment: @developerCK can you suggest me something.

Comment: this query says,

those record  for  username =  "joe@example.com"
whose gadget_data_type =  "Activity" and
whose gadget_sub_data_type =  "running" and
 played xbox and wii both dates before as you write, is there any record in your table. try "OR" b/w gadget type and date

Comment: Yes there are records in the Table. I just tried with OR and it's working. Still don't get how come because both conditions needs to be true.

Comment: i answer that in my answer

Comment: @developerCK by using OR it's only bringing data for the Wii and not XBox whereas in reality there's data for all of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing a range of consecutive dates, there is no need to use the IN operator.

If you use this to compute midnight seven days ago

```
DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY + INTERVAL 0 SECOND
```

here is what you get back:

```
mysql> SELECT DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY + INTERVAL 0 SECOND;
+--------------------------------------------------+
| DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY + INTERVAL 0 SECOND |
+--------------------------------------------------+
| 2012-11-21 00:00:00                              |
+--------------------------------------------------+

1 row in set (0.01 sec)


mysql>
Your query will look like this:

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `user`) FROM `tracks`
WHERE `track_time` >= ( DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY + INTERVAL 0 SECOND );
You also need an index to support the WHERE and COUNT

ALTER TABLE tracks ADD INDEX track_time_user_ndx (track_time,user);
```

Then, the query should go faster.

If you are doing a range of consecutive dates from some earlier period, simply supply the first and last date from midnight to midnight. For example, for the range 2012-11-12 to 2012-11-19:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `user`) FROM `tracks`
WHERE `track_time` >= '2012-11-12 00:00:00'
AND   `track_time` <  '2012-11-19 00:00:00';
If you are doing a range of non-consecutive dates, simply structure the query using UNION. For example, for dates 2012-11-12,2012-11-19,2012-11-26:

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `user`) FROM
(
    SELECT user,track_time FROM `tracks`
    WHERE `track_time` >= '2012-11-12 00:00:00'
    AND   `track_time` <= '2012-11-12 23:59:59'
    UNION
    SELECT user,track_time FROM `tracks`
    WHERE `track_time` >= '2012-11-19 00:00:00'
    AND   `track_time` <= '2012-11-19 23:59:59'
    UNION
    SELECT user,track_time FROM `tracks`
    WHERE `track_time` >= '2012-11-26 00:00:00'
    AND   `track_time` <= '2012-11-26 23:59:59'
)
```

;

Answer (score 0):

Apply  "OR" b/w gadget type and date

**AND Opertaor**

The AND operator selects rows based on the requirement that meet multiple requirements

**OR opearator**

"either or" approach .

beacause of both condition  , that you are applying on same column then it can never happen that both are satisfying at same time.

simple means, take an example

```
col1  col2

a   1
a   2
b   3
```

so (col1=a and col2=1) and (col1=b and col2=3) will never give you any record.

b/c it means col1 having value a and col2 having value 2 with col1 having value b and col2 having value 3.

it simply means adding and operator on same column, will not produce result.

simple example. is it not possible to have

```
 col1=a and col1=b
```